# Tool to connect to a file descriptor for I/O

Tags: linux, unix, io, file-descriptors

I'm looking for a unix tool which can connect me to a specific file descriptor and do some I/O operations on it, assuming that the user permissions are valid. What could I look to use?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you be more specific on the issue you're trying to solve instead of asking for implementation of your idea for solution?

Comment: Here it goes: `echo "some text" > filename` where `filename` is the name of the file of given file descriptor. To read it, `cat filename`, or whatever.